# Swift Mailer vague response code

Tags: php

Have you encountered this error?

"Expected response code(s) [250] but got response []"

There's no response code at all.

I just followed the basic usage of the module. Something like this:

```
$email = new Email("Subject");
$email->to('recipient@mail.com');
$email->message('Message');
$email->send('no-reply@site.com');
```

Not sure on the SMTP configuration though.
Any solution? Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us a portion of code that reproduces the problem ? ;; Just as a precaution : are you sure the configuration for the SMTP server is OK ? *(I don't know how to set that -- but a wrong config might be a cause, I suppose)*

Comment: I've edited the text. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The 250 code represents an acknowledgement of the last client request. If the server is not responding then either the swiftMailer class is very bugy (improbable) or there's something very weird in the server its connecting to.

Have you tried connecting to the same server using a conventional MUA?

C.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same issue however slightly different syntax, but still comes to the same thing

> Expected response code 250 but got
>   code "", with message ""

Its only started happening since I have pointed my scripts at a different mailserver. The strange thing is, the mails actually seem to be getting through. Will post back with my findings